# Why does CodeRunner not recognize my path in VS Code? Using WSL

Tags: vscode-code-runner, coderunner

I'm brand new to programming and I'm getting my environment set up. I'm using CodeRunner on VS Code to get my javascript outputs. In each output though, I'm getting a frustrating error:

```
\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\a\prep-work\Javascript\Udemy\JS3_Conditional
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

I couldn't find any answers on the related CodeRunner Github. I'm pretty sure it's some error with path naming but a few hours of searching and playing with CodeRunner settings have me ready to give up. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The eventual fix with this had to do with the fact that I edited some path in my BIOS - if anyone else gets this error, please undo any modifications you made there, restart and try again!

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I am using WSL2 by default in VS Code terminal and code runner is bringing out these issues. Please explain your solution.

Comment: Hey - I ended up solving it a while ago so I can't be totally precise. From my WSL home directory, I was navigating to my Windows desktop, and opening files there, and editing code in those directories. WSL / codeRunner doesn't like to play around in the native Windows file structure, so make sure you're only accessing files 'downstream' of your WSL home directory if you want to run that code through WSL (and don't change the location of that home directory, like I did!). Hope that helps